# Should we strictly adhere set/get rule

Tags: java

When I have a public exposed class, I usually make its member variables private, together with public accessors and mutators (I try to avoid mutators if possible to make my class immutable).

For example,

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

If the class is for private usage, I will usually

```
private static class Point {
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

As I find the 2nd way is much more convenient for me. Less cumbersome and less typing, although a good IDE may help.

I was wondering, if I have a class for public consumption, is it good that I am using the 2nd approach? (By ensuring my public exposed field will be immutable).

Any shortcoming out from it? Although it seems to violate OOP encapsulation theory, I didn't see a real harm from practical point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a private class, that only the parent class will use, I usually will just put in fields instead of getters and setters. There's no point in adding validation if it won't be used by other, first or third party classes.

Essentially, your class needs to trust itself, and that includes nested classes.

If, however, it's a public class, that will be used by first or third parties, you absolutely should not expose public fields. If you ever need to add validation to the properties, then it becomes a breaking change, because you need to change the public field into two public methods. This is especially true if you're writing library code.

One exception might be if the fields are `final`, as in your example. If it's a small class like `Point`, and it is *completely* immutable, than I would probably just expose the fields as finals. Any validation would occur in the constructor. Just be sure that you won't be adding anything to that class in the future that might break that.

Comment: Yup. I know that hold true for private class. How about public class?

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK Sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough, see edits.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's a good idea to follow the accessors rules given by the JavaBeans convention, because some of the most used frameworks/libraries use it to access internally some fields (for example the expression language).

Is it totally necessary ? **No**, absolutely not, it's a *convention* you can follow it or ignore it. But as many conventions, it has for goal to have a unified way to do something (here access attributes).

If you think that such code takes too much time to develop, you can use your IDE (as you said in your question); if the problem is the completely unnecessary code that you have to generate, I suggest you to take a look at [Lombok Project](http://projectlombok.org/).
Unfortunately there is for now no "good" solutions; the idea to have a different way to access properties in Java has already been seen during [the premises of Java 7](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#property) but finally it won't be a part of the future release of the Java language.

With your public API, I really suggest you to stick to the convention. This way, when a developer want to use any of the component you provide, he won't need to wrap everything in order to access the attributes with getters//setters to make it work with the framework he's using.

A final attribute won't change anything to this problematic, but moreover, you shouldn't have a final attribute because you fear that somebody could modify it from the outside, but only because your attribute must never change and you want it to be final. This is why encapsulation can be so important.

Comment: -1 They are not a part of the way java works, they are a part of the way some frameworks work.  As long as you're not using those frameworks, it's okay.  If you ever use those frameworks, it's not difficult to generate the required getters and setters.

Comment: @Erick Robertson, I updated the answer, Java was a bit too vague, I meant in particular J2EE (hence my example).

Comment: @Colin: The question isn't about J2EE.

Comment: @Erick, it's about a an exposed class, which IMO should follow javabeans conventions to be compatible with other frameworks for example JEE. Even if it's easy for the OP to add getters/setters later, as a an exposed class, it could bother users of this class to not be able to use it with JEE out of the box. I'm not saying you're wrong (see my answer), I'm just saying that it would be better to follow the convention, in particular with exposed classes.

Comment: @Colin: J2EE is not the Java convention.  When writing J2EE code, I can understand that it is good for all public classes to follow JavaBean conventions.  The Java convention, from my understanding, is that any class should not export an API that includes direct modification of class properties.  If a class uses a class that's internal only, however, I don't see a problem with it.  That class can take responsibility for managing this, and no other programmer need be bothered by it.

Comment: @Erick, the question is specifically about "class for public consumption", and I didn't say that JEE was a convention, I just gave it as an example of a commonly used framework using the javabean convention.

Answer (score 0):

Simple data holders (aka structs in C), can spare the get/setters, IMHO. Some modern GUI toolkits like SWT oder Swing all have simple Structured like Rectangle or Point where the elements are accessed directly, and where the classes are part of the public API. Oh, and the toolkits don't have final modifiers on their classes, because often you only change one value (like the x in a rect, to move it to the right).

One reason is that points and rects are often used for return values, in cases where a primitive value is not enought.

So we can conclude **a simple rule where its okey**: If, and only if the class is not likely to change, because it is very simple, and if it is used very often so that the time gain is measurable, and if the attributes are not used in bean binding so no property change event are needed when the properties change, then you might omit the setters and getters.